# Proof verification for the uniqueness of the least upper bound of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Here's how I did it:

> Suppose there are $L, L' \in \mathbb{R}$ and $L \neq L'$. Suppose
>   $L,L'$are both least upper bounds of some set $S$. Then, $\forall s\in S$:
>
> $s \lt L$
>
> $s \lt L'$
>
> Subtracting above two equations:
>
> $0 \lt |L-L'| < \epsilon$
>
> $-\epsilon + L \lt L' < \epsilon +L  $
>
> And this contradicts that $L'$ has to be the least upper bound.
>   Likewise, we derive the same result for $L$. Therefore, $L=L'$.

Comment: why used $\epsilon?$

Comment: I post a solution. Hope it helps

Comment: I just used $\epsilon$ as an arbitrary number.

Comment: Then, why say $\forall s\in S$.......

Comment: I am using $s$ as the arbitrary number in the set S, and $\epsilon$ as some other fixed number. If we let $|L-L'|=a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\epsilon > a.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there are $L, L' \in \mathbb{R}$ and $L\neq L'$. Suppose
$L,L'$are both least upper bounds of some set $S$. So, we want to show that $L=L'$. Because $L$ is an upper bound of $S$ and $L'=\sup S$,
$$L'\leq L.$$
Because $L'$ is an upper bound of $S$ and $L=\sup S$,
$$L\leq L'.$$
Thus, $L=L'$.